# How to get "" in %1 instead of "ECHO is off."

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo, placeholder

```
@echo off
setlocal
title Jupyter Notebook
set init=C:\Users\Sarthik\Machine Learning

set user=%1

echo %user%
if "%user%" == "" (
    set user=%init%
)

echo.
echo Starting Jupyter Notebook at %user%, Please Wait...
echo.
echo.

cd /d %user% && (
jupyter notebook
) || (
echo.
echo.
echo ================== You have entered WRONG PATH ==================
echo.
pause
)
```

I'm quite a newbie in batch and trying to make a custom command to launch Jupyter Notebook from the entered location. I want the command to look like:

```
>jn [filelocation]
```

and when to use the default location just:

```
>jn
```

I was expecting to get "" in `%1` but getting **ECHO is off.** and I can't even check for the equality because of **ECHO** in string. How should I just get "" in `%1`.

*PS: I know I'm getting it because of `@echo off` but I need that statement too.*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question, or code, does not make sense to me, but to get `""` into `%1`, you'd use `jn ""`!

Comment: why would you be expecting "" in %1? What parameters are you starting or calling the Batch with? If you're just running the batch file, %1 is not defined, and therfor when you try and Echo user, User is Undefined. This is why "Echo is off" is displayed.

Comment: Use `echo(%user%` (yes, I know, this looks odd, but it's the only way to echo arbitrary text, even empty one, or `/?`)

Answer (score 0):

Your script has two problems:

1. if you do not pass an argument %1 is empty therefore the line with the `echo %1` command does not work. This is why you get echo is off. Move the line down
2. the line with the cd command does not work if you have a space in the path. You should use quotes in the cd command.

Just a hint: for testing purposes delete the first line (@echo off). In that case you can see the commands which are executed and it is easier to follow what is really happening.

The following script should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal
title Jupyter Notebook
set init=C:\Users\Sarthik\Machine Learning

set user=%1

if "%user%" == "" (
    set user=%init%
)
echo %user%

echo.
echo Starting Jupyter Notebook at %user%, Please Wait...
echo.
echo.

cd /d "%user%" && (
jupyter notebook
) || (
echo.
echo.
echo ================== You have entered WRONG PATH ==================
echo.
pause
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting user to "**`%~1`**" without check if user input argument/parameter is there,
also, you can do the same with path from **`%~1`** ( **`%~dp1`** )

Considering apply quotes in your commands and replace **`.`** (dot) to **`/ , [ , ( or =`**

---

```bat
set "init=C:\Users\Sarthik\Machine Learning"

set "user=%~1"

echo. => echo/ or echo= or echo( or echo= 

if exist "%~dp1\." (do some task ) else another task

rem :: pay attention to use command endlocal if you are usind setlocal!!
```

---

You are setting user to "%~1" without check if user input argument/parameter is there

```bat
rem :: 1st check input if paramenter is not "" and set accordely value in if condition :: 

if not "%~1"=="" (set "_user=%~1") else set "_user=%init%"
```

If you are passing argument **`[file location]`**, with spaces, you need also put quotes:

---

```bat
jn "d:\some folder\with spaces\name path\location"
```

---

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal & title Jupyter Notebook

set "init=C:\Users\Sarthik\Machine Learning"
if not "%~1"=="" (set "_user=%~1") else  set "_user=%init%"

echo/ %_user% & echo/ & echo Starting Jupyter Notebook at %_user%, Please Wait...

if exist "%~dp1\." (echo/ & echo/ & cd /d "%_user%" & jupyter notebook & endlocal & goto :EOF
) else (echo/ & echo/ & echo/ ================== You have entered WRONG PATH ==================)
echo/ & pause & endlocal
```

---

<sub>Sorry my limited **English**</sub>